# Why do we have $\{T\leq t\}=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{s \in \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,t]}\{X_s\leq c+n^{-1}\} \in \mathcal{F}_t $?

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times

Let $T=\inf \{t\geq 0: X_t\leq c\}$. Let $X$ be a continuous and adapted process.

Why do we have $$\{T\leq t\}=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{s \in \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,t]}\{X_s\leq c+n^{-1}\} \in \mathcal{F}_t $$?

My reasoning so far:

$\inf\{t\geq 0:X_t\leq c\}\leq t \Leftrightarrow  \exists_{s \in [0,t]} X_s\leq c$, and so $\{T\leq t\}=\bigcup_{s \in [0,t]}\{X_s\leq c\}$
The problem now, is that we have an uncountable union of $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable sets which may result in a non-measurable set.

So, somehow(not very sure how...), we have
$\bigcup_{s \in [0,t]}\{X_s\leq c\}=\bigcup_{s \in \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,t]}\{X_s\leq c\}$... this makes it a countable union of measurable sets, but I must be missing something...  otherwise, what would be the point of intersecting with the index $n$(this seems to be using continuity)?

Comment: What if $c$ is irrational and   $X_s(\omega) = 2c-s$? Then $T(\omega) = c$, so for  $t=c$ you have $\omega\in\{T\le t\}$ but $\omega\notin \cup_{s\in\Bbb Q\cap[0,t]}\{X_s\le c\}$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thanks. I get it now. ;)